# My microphone is too quiet (seems to be connected with Skype)

Tags: windows-7, skype, microphone

I've been chatting with skype for a long time.. and I don't know why, but for X time it's fine, and then it's too quiet..

Here how it goes :

I'm booting the PC -> getting into a skype call with friends -> talking with friends on skype -> (everything goes well) ->  Closing the skype call -> Going back to a skype call like a hour after -. They can't hear me well, I have to shout so they'll hear me, and in the settings, it's on 100% + 30 DECIBELS, so I can't raise it higher...

and if I'll re-boot my PC, it'll be well until I'll close the skype call again..

Every time I'm skyping with friends well, and then when I close the call and come back after a while, they hear me really low(volume)..

I've been trying to fix this problem for about 2 months! If you'll be able to help me, I'd be so happy.

(btw It's connected not through USB, but through a microphone connection and headphone connection...)
Also, I got Windows 7..

Comment: have you tried other mics or this mic in another computer?

Comment: Yes, they do the same problem too

Comment: have you disabled "Automatically adjust microphone settings" in Skype's settings?

Comment: Do you have a special sound card - there may be a setting in the driver specific software.

Comment: No idea, how can I check ?
Btw,It's a new computer, got it 2 months ago.. (an expensive one if metteres)...

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall Skype(i had similar problem, after i close Skype or end the call all my settings go on default, which i found later). Try to put installation path to another partition/folder and see if problem persist.

I see that you tried other mics on your computer and all of them get same problem ?

Try to update drivers for your sound card.... if you have latest driver i hope that reinstall will solve the problem!

Comment: I've tried to re-install skype,
I've tried other mics..
How do I do the driver part?

Comment: I think that this video will help you :) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k6PG26-l6f0